# get face value from theme

Tags: faces, themes

Is there a way to get a face value defined in theme without enabling it?
Something like:
`(face-theme-background 'org-block-end-line 'my-mega-theme)`

Comment: Why not just open the source code and have a look directly?

Comment: FWIW, you can load a theme without enabling it via `(load-theme THEME t t)`.

Comment: For example It can be used to sort themes into dark or light programmatically I was planning to use it in some questionable shenanigans with `load-theme-buffer-loca` package.

Comment: Consider using `read` on the file with the theme and traversing it's output. You'll have to keep in mind that most theme definitions have more than one top level expression, so just opening a file and using `read` won't cut it.